# Performance of subqueries in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

Both of these queries do the same thing, and one runs about 2.5 x as fast as the other

slow query

```
select sc.countyName
        ,(
    --this adds the distinct number of people who received rehab    
    select count(distinct p2.patientid)
        from statecounties as sc2
        inner join Patient as p2 on p2.stateCode=sc2.stateCode
        and p2.countyCode = sc2.countyCode
        and sc2.stateCode='21'
        inner join Claims as c on c.patientid=p2.patientid
        and c.admissiondate = p2.admissiondate
        and c.dischargedate = p2.dischargedate
        where sc2.countyName=sc.countyname and c.hcpcs in ('97001', '9339', '97002')

     ) as rehabClaims
     --this is the total number of people from each county that visited a hospital with a DRG stroke admission
     ,count(*) as visitCounts
     ,(
    --this adds the distinct number of people who received rehab    
    select count(distinct p2.patientid)
        from statecounties as sc2
        inner join Patient as p2 on p2.stateCode=sc2.stateCode
        and p2.countyCode = sc2.countyCode
        and sc2.stateCode='21'
        inner join Claims as c on c.patientid=p2.patientid
        and c.admissiondate = p2.admissiondate
        and c.dischargedate = p2.dischargedate
        where sc2.countyName=sc.countyname and c.hcpcs in ('97001', '9339', '97002')

     )/count(*) as visitCounts
     from StateCounties as sc
    inner join Patient as p on p.stateCode=sc.stateCode
    and p.countyCode=sc.countyCode
    where sc.stateCode='21'
    group by sc.countyName
    having count(*) > 30
```

fast query

```
select *, round(cast(rehabclaims as float)/VisitCounts *100,2) as percentRehab
from
(
select sc.countyName
        ,(
    --this adds the distinct number of people who received rehab    
    select count(distinct p2.patientid)
        from statecounties as sc2
        inner join Patient as p2 on p2.stateCode=sc2.stateCode
        and p2.countyCode = sc2.countyCode
        and sc2.stateCode='21'
        inner join Claims as c on c.patientid=p2.patientid
        and c.admissiondate = p2.admissiondate
        and c.dischargedate = p2.dischargedate
        where sc2.countyName=sc.countyname and c.hcpcs in ('97001', '9339', '97002')

     ) as rehabClaims
     --this is the total number of people from each county that visited a hospital with a DRG stroke admission
    ,count(*) as visitCounts
    from StateCounties as sc
    inner join Patient as p on p.stateCode=sc.stateCode
    and p.countyCode=sc.countyCode
    where sc.stateCode='21'
    group by sc.countyName
    having count(*) > 30
) t
```

The main difference is that the division in the first one is done on the `sub selects` themselves, whereas on the faster query it uses the sub query (Apologize if my jargon is wrong).   I prefer the second way because it's much easier to read columnName/otherColumnName rather than typing out the entire expressions.  It seems to be the case that this is very often faster as well.  Is there a reason for this, or is this just anecdotal  (proper indexes apply)

Comment: Have you examined the execution plans?

Comment: I'm more or less naive to their actual meanings, but yes, I'm gandered at them.  Couldn't really glean much.

Comment: In the first version, it's _probably_ actually executing the (same) sub-query twice.  Code that only needs to be run once will be faster than code that ends up being run twice, besides being (potentially) safer (due to multi-threading/concurrent use issues).  You might also try putting the sub-query in a common-table-expression (CTE), which is pretty much a way to define an inline view (the `WITH` clause).

Comment: thanks for the insight. the more i delve into it, it seems that CTEs are the way to go most of the time.  i just don't right them as naturally as i do something akin to the above.